# ggparcoord plot with gaps

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

In geosciences, we often use parallel coordinate plots with values normalized to, e.g. a chondrite meteorite.

When you plot a REE Chondrite normalized plot, you plot all the rare earth elements (La, Ce, Pr, Nd, Pm, Sm, Eu, Gd, Tb, Dy, Ho, Er, Tm Yb, Lu). However, as the half life for Pm is very short, you cannot have analyses for this element. Nevertheless, in the REE Chondrite plots, you still include Pm, but without datapoints. The line still runs through it. This is so that you can readily compare your patterns to other patterns. Here is an example: [First image from a google search](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ajeet_Milliard2/publication/299626047/figure/fig10/AS:427301163802634@1478887945265/Chondrite-normalized-rare-earth-element-REE-plots-of-igneous-rocks-from-the-Pequop_W640.jpg)

I would like to produce a similar plot, however i cannot figure out how to "skip" Pm in my plot an leave a gap in the datapoints, but still have a line running through the gap.

Here is an example:

```
Sample <- c("sample1", "sample2")
Pr <- c(1,5)
Nd <- c(2,4) 
Pm <- c(NA,NA)
Sm <- c(3,3)
Eu <- c(4,2)

df <- data.frame(Sample, Pr, Nd, Pm, Sm, Eu)
```

I now would like to produce the parallel coordinate plot in the following fashion:

```
ggparcoord(df, columns = 2:6, showPoints=TRUE, scale="globalminmax")
```

However, since I have *NA*s in my dataframe, it won't work with scale="globalminmax".

Any idea on how I could still produce a parallel coordinate plot and keep Pm in the plot?

EDIT:

An example with 3 samples organized in 2 groups:

```
Sample <- c("sample1", "sample2","sample3")
grouping <- c("gr1","gr2","gr1")
Pr <- c(1,5,1)
Nd <- c(2,4,1) 
Pm <- c(NA,NA,NA)
Sm <- c(3,3,1)
Eu <- c(4,2,1)

df <- data.frame(Sample, grouping, Pr, Nd, Pm, Sm, Eu)
```

The lines and datapoints should be coloured according to "grouping", while the lines should only connect individual samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this doesn't use ggally but base ggplot2, but I think it is roughly how I interpret your description of the plot.

```
# Wide to long format
df2 <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = "Sample")
# Omit NAs
df2 <- df2[!is.na(df2$value),]

ggplot(df2, aes(variable, value, colour = Sample, group = Sample)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  # Set limits to keep 'Pm' in axis
  scale_x_discrete(limits = levels(df2$variable))
```

[image]

EDIT: To adress the grouping, yes you can. I didn't know exactly what variable you'd be colouring in this case, feel free to swap `colour` and `group` aesthetics in the example below.

```
df2 <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = c("Sample", "grouping"))
df2 <- df2[!is.na(df2$value),]

ggplot(df2, aes(variable, value, colour = grouping, group = Sample)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = levels(df2$variable))
```

Comment: yes, this looks very promising! thank you very much.

I will update when I have tried it out.

Comment: Is there a way where I can have multiple samples organized in, lets say, two groups?
(I edited the original post with an updated example)

Comment: Yes, you could, I've edited my answer with some example code.